# Opening two Excel sheets on two separate Excel application instances

Tags: xlwings

I'm very new to python language and xlwings.  I just want to accomplish something very simple.
I have two excel sheets, a.xlsx and b.xlsx.   I know how to open them using the common xlwings Python API via the following
xw.Book(r'C:/path/to/a.xlsx')
xw.books.open(r'C:/path/to/a.xlsx')

However, when I try to add an excel instance and try to open the excels,  I do not know the command structure (object hirearachy) to open them in two independent instance of Ms Excel app.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open them each in different instances, this should work. Please see the docs under Book, https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#book . Once you do it for the first instance, do the same for the second, with the new instance pid.

```
import xlwings as xw

>>>app = xw.App() # Create new instance
>>>app.pid # Get pid to point at.
30332
>>>xw.apps[30332].books.open(r'C:/path/to/a.xlsx')
```